# How do you prove $S_{XYZT} \leq \dfrac{1}{5} S_{ABCD} $?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

In the given figure, $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral. Suppose that $M, N, P, Q$ are mid-points of $AB, BC, CD, DA$, respectively. Prove that $S_{XYZT} \leq \dfrac{1}{5} S_{ABCD} $ where $S_{ABCD}$ (resp. $S_{XYZT}$) is the area of $ABCD$ (resp. $XYZT$)?

[image]

Could you please give a key hint to solve this exercise? Thank you so much for your discussions!

Comment: What have you tried? This can be coordinate-germ brute forced out, so where are you stuck?

Comment: According to `geogebra` the ratio is not exactly 5. Especially the ratio tends to 6 if one of the sides tends to 0.

Comment: @CalvinLin  I tried to do with the coodinates of points and calculate areas. However, i prefer to find another nice solution. Thank you so much for your interests.

Comment: @user Thank you so much for your nice answers. Can you give a  reference for the case that ratio which tends to 6?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Quadrilateral formed by connecting the vertices of a convex quadrilateral to midpoints of non-adjacent sides"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1925901/409), with a reference to the 2011 *Mathematics Magazine* article ["Crosscut Convex Quadrilaterals"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.84.1.016). [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999662/409) shows that the ratio of inner area to total area is between $1:6$ and $1:5$.

Comment: Thank you very much for everyone. I updated my question, it should be $S_{XYZT} \leq \dfrac{1}{5} S_{ABCD} $.

Comment: @Blue Oh, great! Thank you so much for your doccuments.

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out in a comment the ratio
$\dfrac{S_{ABCD}}{S_{TXYZ}}$ is not exactly equal to 5, though it is surprisingly close to the value almost in any convex quadrilateral. Only if one side tends to 0 (so that the quadrilateral degenerates to triangle) the ratio tends to 6 (as it also should).

There is however a class of quadrilaterals for which the ratio is exactly 5. This class is parallelograms, and the proof in this case is simple.
[image]

As easy to understand for *any* convex quadrilateral:
$$
S_{TXYZ}=S_{AXM}+S_{BYN}+S_{CZP}+S_{DTQ}.
$$
and
$$
S_{ABCD}-S_{TXYZ}=S_{AYB}+S_{BZC}+S_{CTD}+S_{DXA}.
$$
Specifically for parallelogram we have:
$$
S_{AYB}=4S_{AXM}, \dots
$$
Thus,
$$S_{ABCD}-S_{TXYZ}=4S_{TXYZ}.$$

---

*UPDATE:*

On the basis of numerical evidence I would conjecture the following statement:

*For any convex quadrilateral $$5\le\dfrac{S_{ABCD}}{S_{TXYZ}}<6$$ and the ratio is equal to 5 if and only if the quadrilateral $TXYZ$ is a trapezoid.*

For the characterization of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ the above statement means that its vertices lie on four *equidistant* parallel lines, two opposite vertices being on the external lines (see figure below). I do not know if a special name for such a quadrilateral exists.

To prove the "if" part of the statement only a slight modification of the previous proof (for parallelogram) is required due to the fact that $S_{AXM}=S_{DTQ}$ and $S_{BYN}=S_{CZP}$.

[image]

Comment: Yes,  your solution is the best for your special class. However, Can you say more about this point?  ``There is however a class of quadrilaterals for which the ratio is exactly 5. This class is parallelograms''.  Are there the other such classes or not?

Comment: @mathJuan See update of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice update!

Answer (score 0):

►Let the four vertex $C=(0,0),D=(d_1,d_2),A=(a_1,a_2),B=(b_1,b_2)$.

►Calculation determines lines $\overline{BQ},\overline{ND},\overline{MC},\overline{AP}$.

►Points $Y=\overline{BQ}\cap\overline{MC}\\X=\overline{BQ}\cap\overline{AP}\\Z=\overline{ND}\cap\overline{MC}\\T=\overline{ND}\cap\overline{AP}$

►Do you know how to calculate directly the area of a convex quadrilateral? For example for $CDAB$ put the coordinates as follows starting from an arbitrary vertice and contrary to clockwise direction, say starting with $C=(0,0)$

$$0\hspace{10mm}0 \\d_1\hspace{10mm}d_2\\a_1\hspace{10mm}a_2\\b_1\hspace{10mm}b_2\\0\hspace{10mm}0$$ You must finish repeating the first chosen vertice.Then here you have the area is given for 
$$\frac12[(0\cdot d_2+d_1\cdot a_2+a_1\cdot b_2+b_1\cdot0)-(0\cdot  b_2+b_1\cdot a_2+a_1\cdot d_2+d_1\cdot0)]$$ (Multiplication descending for positive parenthesis and ascending for the negative one).

Repeat this with the smaller quadrilateral and compare.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your solution. In fact,  one can  suppose that $D(d_1; 0)$. I prefer to see the other ways to solve this problem. However, I like your solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that with this answer you have a direct way to verify if in fact your formula with the $5$ is true or not. I wanted to leave you this task.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just updated again my question. It should be $S_{XYZT} \leq \dfrac{1}{5} S_{ABCD} $. Thank you very much  one again for your nice hints.