# Generalizing Routh's Theorem to quadrilaterals

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area, projective-geometry

[Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%27s_theorem) gives the area of a triangle determined by three cevians in a parent triangle, in terms of the "Ceva ratios" for those cevians.

After learning about Routh's theorem, I started thinking of possible generalizations. The question I came up with is

> Can a similar formula be found for quadrilaterals with a similar construction?

That is, for convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, construct points $M$, $N$, $P$, $Q$ on sides $BC$, $CD$, $DA$, and $AB$, respectively, and take $S$, $T$, $U$, $V$ to be the intersections of lines $AM$ and $BN$, $BN$ and $CP$, etc.

[image]

Then, find an expression for the area of $\square STUV$ in terms of the ratios in which the points $M$, $N$, $P$, and $Q$ divide the sides of $\square ABCD$.

The method I thought of using to solve this problem was applying a transformation to $\square ABCD$, turning it into a square (so that the problem of finding the required area would be easy to solve), but I am not sure why such a transformation would preserve area ratios. In particular, I am interested in the case where points $M$, $N$, $P$, $Q$ lay in the middle of the sides of $\square ABCD$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Regarding transformations ... *Linear transformations* are nice in that they preserve ratios of parallel segments; in particular, midpoints of segments transform to midpoints of transformed segments. And they do, in fact, preserve ratios of areas. Unfortunately, not every quadrilateral is linearly transformable to a square. The best you could do is, say, transform $\triangle ABC$ to an isosceles right triangle; point $D$ would just be "out there" somewhere. That can still simplify the work a bit, as you can coordinatize with, say, $A=(0,1)$, $B=(0,0)$, $C=(1,0)$, $D=(p,q)$.

Comment: For your specific case it seems to be very close to 5 according to Geogabra. May be the variation from 5 is due to calculation error.

Comment: @Blue I tried solving the problem using either vectors or complex numbers, but both seem to heavy on calculations. I was hoping that due to the simple nature of the problem statement, a syntethic approach might exist.

Comment: @Moti That's exactly what I thought!:) The answer I got from drawing the figure in Geogebra was between 4.9 and 5.1, so I thought this might be due to calculation errors.

Comment: To the extent you're only interested in the midpoint case, that question is [asked and answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1925901/409), showing a range of area ratios between $1:6$ and $1:5$. (The $1:6$ ratio arises when the parent triangle degenerates into a triangle.) There's also a reference to a journal article about the result. ... Anyway, what this indicates is that, unlike with a triangle, the quadrilateral area ratio is not determined by the "Ceva ratios" alone; the shape of the figure matters.

Comment: @Blue Thank you so much for your help!